How do I forward smtp requests on port 25 to my local machine on another port on my VPS
I need to receive emails, but for that I need port 25 open which my ISP blocks.
I purchased a VPS and now I want to accept the smtp requests on it and forward it to my machine on another port.
I have ubuntu installed, how do I do this?

Your SMTP server does not have to run on port 25. How did you determine your ISO blocks port 25?

@Ramhound, when port forwarding port 25 its says that you can not open it.
Most of the big mail companies always send their emails on port 25

Are both systems running Ubuntu? Are you looking for direct forwarding, or would SMTP relaying be acceptable? Email has good support for multi-hop delivery.

My local machine is running on windows, as far as I know you use SMTP relaying to send emails from a different server but I never heard of it going the other way (well that is what I am trying to do). At the moment I am trying to forward it directly to my local machine

@dani - You will receive emails regardless of if it's on port 25 or 2525. Sadly, if running the service on another port isn't an option, then SMTP relaying likely is your only solution other than paying your ISP not to block port 25. "its says that you can not open it." - What is "it"?
